# CSS to specify positions over a scanned document

Tags: css, printing, positioning

I'm trying to write the CSS rules to position text over a scanned document.

Reason: The document is a pre-printed form. I am trying to position the text on-screen so that it relates to the 'spaces' on the actual form.

Issue: Although I position the values using centimeters, they don't seem to get aligned with the ones on the actual page. I can see this misalignment since my scanned image is in the background of the page.

What I've tried:

1. I used a ruler to physically measure the locations and specify them with CSS. But on-screen, it doesn't tally.
2. I used the scanned image to position the CSS values. Then the printout is not correct.
3. I even scaled the scanned page using Inkscape to the exact dimensions in centimeters and took into account all margins, etc...

What I need: I am trying to correctly show the output values on-screen AND have them print in the correct manner as well. I know that using two CSS sheets (one for print) is an option. But I'm developing this program away from where the actual printing is to be done. So is there a convenient way of matching the exact screen locations with those on the actual/final prinout?

Thanks!

Comment: are you adding background to the body element or a relative container. I suggest you to create a relative container of the size of the image and use absolute positioning for elements.

Comment: @darkapple thank you for your input. I'm using the background image within a div, and the margins are being set correctly. However, the output on screen doesn't match the one on print (on the pre-printed doc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scanned document is like any other image, Use it as a background and absolutely-postion the elements on top of it. Make all of your measurements in pixels, not centimetres.

Comment: you method seems by far the most practical. But my problem is that when this is printed as hardcopy, it doesn't seem to map the values to the positions. I think it's something to do with the resolution of the printer/screen.

Comment: Browsers are crappy as printing. To get it right, generate a PDF server-side.

Comment: I tried your method hoping it should work. Unfortunately, it didn't. I'm developing on Ubuntu + Firefox, and testing on Windows + FF/IE. Even on the same browser, the positioning is different, when the OS changed. Thanks for your tip anyway.

Comment: it comes down to square one. I have to settle with your answer - it's the closest I got up to now :)

There's no perfect solution to this but I guess your method is the best so far. But I improvised by sticking to CM measures for print only. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't have to settle just yet, I am still willing to work with you to figure out how to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an specific CSS stylesheet for printing, even if you don't have the printer near you as you say. It must be done this way... No matter how many times you measure in your screen, the printer will print different. The CSS it's needed but the real deal it's the printer internal configuration that you must get and understand.

You should read this tutorial, I found it useful!
[How to Setup a Print Style Sheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) by **Smashing Magazine**.

HOWEVER that's not enough... You really need to ask all possible details about the printer! With the model of the printer at hand, if the people who actually prints on it doesn't know, you can look for the default margins it has when it prints, you really should know them. If they don't tell you or you don't find them, there must be a way to tell the printer to print it's internal configuration. I needed to press some buttons in some order some seconds to do this in the model I needed to print. As you, I don't have it by my side.

I done this once and I was struggling until I had to print that information. The printer knew everything! It's margins, it's measures, how much pixels was considering from left to right, from right to left, etc. All you need it's there and you need to know it to print flawlessly your format adapting your CSS to this immovable-by-provider values.

As a personal recommendation, you should follow [Smashing Magazine on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/smashingmag) =) I find very interesting their tweets about web design and CSS =)

Good luck! =)

Comment: thank you for descriptive info. Do you specify the positions for printing using px or cm?

Comment: Basically you'll need to take in consideration the DPI (Dots Per Inch) of your printer and use the pixels measurements in your CSS and transform them into centimeters for the printer version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use coordinates with JS.

1. Use a design software (paint can be the tool..) to obtain the coordinates of each element you have to place
2. Use JS to place elements with the coordinates you have

It can do the job, and the coordinates are better than measurements..

Comment: no matter whether you specify the positions in JS or CSS, the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal solution, but I thought I might helped you get the positioning correct on the screen.

I would create a dynamic test grid on top of the form so you know where the positions are.

Similar to this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 500px; $i++)
{
      for($j = 0; $j < 500px; $j++)
      {
         echo '<span class="gridPoint" style="position:absolute; top:'.$i.'; left:'.$j.'">' . $i . ',' . $j .'</span>';
      }
}
```

This would allow to see the exact coordinates, the text would have to be very small, but it could make life a lot easier.

Comment: this is a good idea to plan your layouts but the issue is in mapping the screen positions to the printer's. This seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the scanned image with a fixed width and height in pixels before you start. Then overlay the words using pixels as well. That way when you print, it should line up because both are pixels. Your text size  as well as line-height should also be specified in pixels.

If that doesn't work, it should be really telling to see exactly *how* it doesn't work. Are the lines of text correct, but all shifted a certain number of pixels up or down? Then it's probably a line-height issue. Is the text lined up correctly by line, but the words get out of sync as the line progresses? Probably has to do with different letter and word spacing. Etc.

Comment: Thank you fory your efforts. If you look at the issues being mentioned so far, I think you'll find that we've already tried these. For example, even on the SAME browser, the layouts look different when viewed on a different screen. And the issue is that although the background was scaled and values placed pixel by pixel, the alignments differ on screen and printer. Thanks gain for your inputs

Comment: In what way are they misaligned? Is it only with text, or would it do it with anything? For example, say your image is 100x100px: if you position four 1px by 1px divs absolutely on the image in locations 0,0; 0,100; 100,0; and 100,100; what happens when you print? Where do the divs go?

Comment: For example, http://jsfiddle.net/qnsF5/2/ prints with the dots exactly in the corners.